# Guid string in primary key in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a problem regarding temporary values in primary keys in EF Core (2.1.4).
The value is too long to fit in the database and validation using the DataAnnotations.Validator fails. 
If I disable the validator `dbcontext.SaveChanges` works and handle the value in the correct way.

I have an example table (SQL Server) with this definition:

```
TestTable
Key1 numeric (18,0)
Key2 char (1) Default value: A
```

`Key1` and `Key2` are defined as primary key on the table.
`Key2` has a default value of A.

This table is reverse engineered in EF Core to this POCO:

```
public partial class TestTable
{
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(18, 0)")]
    public decimal Key1 { get; set; }
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Key2 { get; set; }
}
```

Note that we are using data annotations on the POCO classes.

The model generated looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TestTable>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Key1, e.Key2 });
    entity.Property(e => e.Key2)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("('A')");
});
```

I then add a new item to the `dbcontext`.

```
var testTbl = new TestTable { Key1 = 90};
db.TestTable.Add(testTbl);
db.Validate();
db.SaveChanges();
```

I don't specify `Key2` as I want to use the default value from the database.

Before I call `Context.SaveChanges()` on the dbcontext I would like to validate the entities in the dbcontext.
This best way I have found for that until now is:

```
Public void Validate()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || 
    e.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(e => e.Entity)
    .ToList();

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var vContxt = new ValidationContext(entity);
        List<ValidationResult> validaRes = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (!Validator.TryValidateObject(entity, validationContext, 
            validationResults, true))
        {
            //Handle validation errors.
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I add the `TestTable` object to the dbcontext, `Key2` string property automatically get assigned a guid value.
When Validate is called it fails because `Key2` is not supposed to have a string value longer than 1 character.

If `Key2` is not part of the primary key and I remove it from the HasKey method like this:

```
entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Key1 });
```

Then `Key2` don't get a guid value assigned and the validation works.

Does someone know if there is a way to tell EF Core to not add a guid value to a string value that are part of a key and don't have a value specified?
Or is there a way to tell EF Core to obey the data annotation rules defined on the POCO object when assigning a temporary value?

Comment: You didn't set any value to `Key2` which means it's *NULL*. That's a bug. You can't have a NULL value in a primary key. EF Core should have thrown an exception in this case. Did you configure `Key2` as a database-generated value perhaps? What does your context configuration look like?

Comment: If you want `Key2` to be only 1 character long, you should probably change it to a `Char` instead of `String`

Comment: If I remove Validate the code works and the default value is used and no exception is thrown.
I use Scaffold-DbContext to reverse engineer database into code and it generate the property as a string, I don't know why Microsoft think it should be a string. 
But we run the scaffolding tool everytime the database change and generate a new model, so I hope to find a solution without too much manual change in generated code.

Answer (score 0):

A *composite primary key* can only be defined by the fluent api.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

> Composite keys can only be configured using the Fluent API - conventions will never setup a composite key and you can not use Data Annotations to configure one.

However, you can even use data annotation.
You can use the `DatabaseGenerated` attribute.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties

```
public partial class TwoKeysTable
{
    public decimal Key1 { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Key2 { get; set; }

    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use fluent api:

```
entity.Property(e => e.Key2)
         .HasMaxLength(1)
         .HasDefaultValueSql("('A')")
         .ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); // add this
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I used Scaffold-DbContext with annotations, which generated the composite key through Fluent API as you can see in the line `entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Key1, e.Key2 });`
I added ValueGeneratedOnAdd but it didn't change anything. I don't know if it is because Key2 is part of a composite key.
I changed HasDefaultValueSql to HasDefaultValue, but it made no difference.

Comment: Error: "The field Key2 must be a string with a maximum length of 1" because there is a guid string in the property. 
I guess it is a temporary value assigned by EF Core that is first replaced during SaveChanges and because Validate is called before SaveChanges, then the property has not got the right value assigned.

Comment: I have just tried adding a new column (Field3) with the same specification as Key2 to the table, but with the exception that the column is not a key, but it is still required to be not null and also have a default value specified.
When Validate is called it complains that Field3 do not have a value. So it seems like the default value is just not passed to the Poco object before SaveChanges is called :-/